# Getting an object from MongoDB using its id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Let me explain my problem first.
I am trying to get the ID from URL and use it to find a record in the database(MongoDB). The following code I have in NodeJS Express App.

```
app.post('/dashboard/profile/update/:id',function(req,res){
   var to_update=req.params.id;
   var firstName=req.body.fname;
   obj_to_search={_id:to_update};
   db.open(function(err, dbs) {
       if(!err) {
           dbs.collection('project',function(err, collection) {
         //update
               collection.findOne(obj_to_search, function(err, result) {
                   if (err) {
                       throw err;
                   } else {
                       res.send(result);
                   }
                   dbs.close();
               });
           });
        }
    });
});
```

I am getting the record if I hard code the ID to 1. But I am not getting the record by this way. However I have checked using `console.log` the ID i am getting through URL is also 1.

Comment: What is `typeof to_update` in the two cases? You might have to convert it.

Comment: This actually solved my problem :)
I had to convert ID from URL to int.

Answer (score 0):

### Convert strings to integers

If a variable is in the url - it's a string. If you're wanting to query the database with a number, you'll need to cast it to a number for use in the query:

```
obj_to_search={_id: parseInt(to_update,10)};
```